# How to display a json image as listView

Tags: android, json, image

Guys I'm trying to display a json image in my app,I cannot find any tutorial which is doing this king of thing,I'm getting the images as string but converting it as bitmap is my main problem.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
            URL url = new URL(
                  "myUrl" + c.getString("photoThumbnailUrl"));

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            map.put(TAG_PHOTOS, photoThumbnailUrl);
            // System.out.println(photoThumbnailUrl);
            map.put(photoThumbnailUrl, bitmap);
```

Binding the images into the adapter

```
          SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, List, R.layout.list,
            new String[] { TAG_PHOTOS,TAG_IDENTIFIER }, new int[] {    
            R.id.image,R.id.identifier });
            adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my logCat

```
          Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for photoThumbnailUrl
          W/System.err(592): org.json.JSONException: No value for photoThumbnailUrl
          W/System.err(592):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that yor json file have the property photoThumbnailUrl?

can you show us the json file from the url request?

Comment: Yes it has,and I have now added the json into the main question.